# How to create one thread for slowly logging so that the main jobs can continue running (in python)?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, logging

I have main works with heavy calculations and also logging with many IO operations.
I don't care much about either the speed or the order of logging.
What I want is a log collector who can take the context I want to log in a new thread so that my main script can keep running without being blocked.

The code I tried is as below:

```py
import threading
from loguru import logger
from collections import deque
import time

class ThreadLogger:

    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, daemon=True)
        self.log_queue = deque()
        self.thread.start()
        self.run()

    def run(self):
    # I also have tried while True:
        while self.log_queue:
            log_func, context = self.log_queue.popleft()
            log_func(*context)

    def addLog(self, log_func, context):
        self.log_queue.append([log_func, context])



thlogger = ThreadLogger()
for i in range(20):
    # add log here with new thread so that won't affect main jobs
    thlogger.addLog(logger.debug, (f'hi {i}',))
    # main jobs here (I want to do some real shit here with heavy calculation)
```

The code above doesn't really work as my expectation.

It cannot detect by itself when to digest the queue

Also, if I use "while True: " it just blocks the queue that the queue is never getting longer.

All other techniques I can come out with aren't really doing on a new single thread

Any suggestions I would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the call `self.run()` as you already have started a thread to run that method. And it is that call that is blocking your program. It causes the main thread to sit blocked on the empty queue.

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, daemon=True)
        self.log_queue = deque()
        self.thread.start()
        #self.run() # remove
```

Once you do that then you can change `while self.log_queue:` to `while True:`

Comment: So simple! and It works!
great thanks!
One more question
Do you think a forever "while True" would be problematic to waste computing power?
Or this design is ok?

Comment: You might want to use a `queue.Queue` rather than a `deque` as it has a blocking `get` that would allow the thread to wait idle for the next queue item rather than busy waiting.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan D.'s answer

```py
import threading
from loguru import logger
from collections import deque
import time

class ThreadLogger:

    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, daemon=True)
        self.log_queue = deque()
        self.thread.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.log_queue:
                log_func, context = self.log_queue.popleft()
                log_func(*context)

    def addLog(self, log_func, context):
        self.log_queue.append([log_func, context])
            

thlogger = ThreadLogger()
for i in range(20):
    thlogger.addLog(logger.debug, (f'hi {i}',))

time.sleep(1)  # wait for log to happen
```